# How to remove bookmarks when using wicked_pdf gem in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf, ruby-on-rails-5.2, wicked-gem

I am using Ruby 2.5.3p105 and Rails 5.2.0 . And gem 'wicked_pdf' 1.1.0  for pdf download.
From below picture, on hover I am getting bar in the top which include several things like title, page no, rotate, download, print, and last one is bookmarks. I want to remove bookmarks from this sheet. How can I achieve this?

[image]

My Codes are:

home_controller.rb:

```
pdf = render_to_string pdf: "#{@selected_scheme_code}.pdf", 
                            template: "/home/overview_download.html.erb", 
                            encoding: "UTF-8", 
                            layout: 'pdf.html.erb',
                            disposition: "attachment",
                            title: "Fund Factsheet",                               
                            :page_size => "A4",
                            margin: {top: 0,
                                  bottom: 0,
                                  left: 0,
                                  right: 0},                             
                            :javascript_delay => 5000,
                            save_to_file: save_path, 
                            :extra => '--no-stop-slow-scripts',                                
                            save_only: true
    File.open(save_path, "wb") do |file|
        file << pdf
      end
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the pdf generated by your gem, it's just the PDF viewer that displays these options.

Comment: But,  title: "Fund Factsheet", is working which is included in my code. If I change the title in my code, the title will be changed.

Comment: If you don't want your PDF viewer to display a title bar, then you need to turn off the title bar in your PDF viewer.

Answer (score 1):

When you create pdf file, this file has title, content, ... You open this file with PDF viewer, title is showed and page no, download, print, bookmark button are PDF viewer options.
So you can't remove bookmark button from this. :D